# Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-access, mongodump

I'm trying to mongodump a remote EC2 instance of MongoDB from my local Ubuntu 14:

```
mongodump --host 12.345.678.90 --sslCAFile ~/aws/remoteinstance.pem
```

but I get the following error:

> Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

I've read these documentations: [Backup and restore with MongoDB tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/), [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongodump/)

I've also tried to use the --username options and put there my remote EC2 Ubuntu username:

```
mongodump --host 12.345.678.90 --sslCAFile ~/aws/remoteinstance.pem --username ubuntu@12.345.678.90
```

Then I was asked to enter a password, but since I don't have a password, I left it empty, and I got the same error message.

I've found many questions with the same title, but they were all about cases than people tried to connect to their local instance and got that error for some reason.

BTW I connect to both my EC2 instance and its MongoDB instance frequently, so I'm sure that I know the credentials and that the .pem file is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance the server is running in a replica set?

Comment: @gsaslis I think not, since I don't know what a replica set is and I'm the one who set up this server.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [mongodump option docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--port), if you don't specify `--ssl` or `--port`, the by default mongodump tries to connect to the host you specify via TCP on port 27017.

Either try:

1. adding `--ssl` to your mongodump options or
2. alter your ec2 security group on each machine to allow TCP on port 27017.

Comment: Port 27017 it open in the security group. I know for sure because I also connect to my remote MongoDB using RoboMongo. I tried to add "--ssl" to the options, in addition to "--sslCAFile", and then I got this error message: Failed: can't create session: error configuring the connector: openssl configuration: LoadClientCAFile: SSL errors: system library:fopen:No such file or directory
BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib